# php SplFixedArray no longer Iterator but InteratorAggregate

Tags: php, data-structures, bitcoin

Now that SplFixedArray is not an Interator but rather an IteratorAggregate how do i change below code to work for PHP 8

```php
<?php 

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace BitWasp\Bitcoin\Transaction\Mutator;

abstract class AbstractCollectionMutator implements \Iterator, \ArrayAccess, \Countable
{
    /**
     * @var \SplFixedArray
     */
    protected $set;

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function all(): array
    {
        return $this->set->toArray();
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isNull(): bool
    {
        return count($this->set) === 0;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function count(): int
    {
        return $this->set->count();
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    public function rewind()
    {
        $this->set->rewind();
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function current()
    {
        return $this->set->current();
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function key()
    {
        return $this->set->key();
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    public function next()
    {
        $this->set->next();
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function valid()
    {
        return $this->set->valid();
    }

    /**
     * @param int $offset
     * @return bool
     */
    public function offsetExists($offset)
    {
        return $this->set->offsetExists($offset);
    }

    /**
     * @param int $offset
     */
    public function offsetUnset($offset)
    {
        if (!$this->offsetExists($offset)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Offset does not exist');
        }

        $this->set->offsetUnset($offset);
    }

    /**
     * @param int $offset
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function offsetGet($offset)
    {
        if (!$this->set->offsetExists($offset)) {
            throw new \OutOfRangeException('Nothing found at this offset');
        }
        return $this->set->offsetGet($offset);
    }

    /**
     * @param int $offset
     * @param mixed $value
     */
    public function offsetSet($offset, $value)
    {
        $this->set->offsetSet($offset, $value);
    }
}
```

I tried to just change implements \Iterator to \InteratorAggregate but its not working right.

Answer (score 0):

**SplFixedArray** was and still is a *Traversable*, however it changed it's interface: From *Iterator* to *IteratorAggregate* and with it it's protocol.

This now erodes your abstract superclass **AbstractCollectionMutator** as it still implements the earlier Iterator protocol and does not fulfill the IteratorAggregate protocol yet.

This is straight forward:

1. Remove the *Iterator* interface.
2. Delete rewind(), valid(), key(), current() and next().
3. Then implement the *IteratorAggregate* interface.
4. Add the getIterator() method.
5. Run tests, commit, push and done.

The implementation is the same as you had earlier, you delegate to the set, with the benefit that you can use the set itself now, you don't need to forward the protocol in a Traversable<*IteratorAggregate*>:

```php
abstract class AbstractCollectionMutator implements \IteratorAgregate /* formerly \Iterator */, [...]

    public function getIterator(): Traversable {
         return $this->set;
    }

[...]
```

No event forwarding necessary, `$this->set->getIterator()` is implicit for any Traversable with *IteratorAggregate* interface. PHP implements that protocol internally.